# Get the combination from other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array

First

```
array(
0 => 100000,
1 => 50000,
2 => 100000,
3 => 100000);
```

Second

```
array(
0 => 150000,
1 => 200000,);
```

The problem is I want to get the combination from first array that formed each second array.

Example
Second array index 0 can be formed from first array index 0 and 1 and second array index 1 can be formed from first array index 2 and 3

I want to achieve like this

```
[0 => [0,1] , 1 => [2,3]]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why you need to do this ?and have you tried ? what are the limitations ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand : you want only ONE wayt to achieve the result of second array with item of first array? Because you can achieve the second array index 0 (15000) with multiple key of first item : 0 + 1, 1 + 2 or 1 + 3 for example. You want only one possibility? And ofc, what did you try so far?

Comment: I need this to pair exact value from first array to second array. I have tried it by generating all the possible combination from first array e.g [ [0,1] , [1,2] , [1,3] , [0,2], [0,3] ] but i can't pair exact value from first array with second array

Comment: can you share more example ?

Comment: the point is i want only one possibility from this ([ [0,1] , [1,2] , [1,3] , [0,2], [0,3] ]) to formed each second array value.

Comment: what if `0 => 250000,
1 => 100000` ?

Comment: if 0 => 250000, 1 => 100000 then [0 => [0,1,2] , 1 => [3]]

Comment: And you want only one combination to build the second, or all combinations?

Comment: @Philipp yes i want only one and unique combination for each second array value, like I said before

Comment: Can you comment on below answers given ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple an fast gready approach would be to first sort the arrays descending. After that, loop over the second one and collect from the first one as much values, till you reach your desired value.

```
$first = [
    0 => 100000,
    1 => 50000,
    2 => 100000,
    3 => 100000
];

$second = [
    0 => 150000,
    1 => 200000
];

arsort($first);
arsort($second);

$combinations = [];
foreach ($second as $search) {
    $combination = [];
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($first as $key => $val) {
        if ($sum + $val > $search) continue;
        $sum += $val;
        $combination[] = $key;
        if ($sum == $search) break;
    }
    if ($sum != $search) die("nothing found this way..");
    foreach ($combination as $val) unset($first[$val]);
    $combinations[] = $combination;
}

print_r($combinations);
```

Comment: You shared a good solution, but personally it would be great if value exist in instead `[0 => [0,1] , 1 => [2,3]]` just keys, also, in your anwser is it fine if `$second = [
    0 => 150000,
    1 => 800000
];` giving `nothing found this way`

Comment: @C2486 I dont get your problem with the first example? Is it, because I return `[0,2], [3,1]`? The second - what else should the algo do? Returning a partly solution doesn't seems correct

Comment: Yeah, it looks great, I didn't check but seems it would give same output for `0 => 150000,
    1 => 200000` and `0 => 200000,
    1 => 150000`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its very good solution. I think i can start digging from here

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple idea to achieve your requirement. There would be many if's and but you need to consider yourself

```
<?php
$arr1 = [0 => 100000,1 => 50000,2 => 100000,3 => 100000];
$arr2 = [0 => 150000,1 => 200000];
//$arr2 = [0 => 250000,1 => 100000];
$count = 0;
$new = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){

  if($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$count]){
     $new[$arr2[$count]] = $arr1[$i];
     $count++;
  }else{
    $sum = [$arr1[$i]];
    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($arr1);$j++){
      $sum[] = $arr1[$j];
      if( array_sum($sum) == $arr2[$count]){
        $new[$arr2[$count]] = $sum;
        $count++;
      }
    }
  }  
}
print_r($new);
?>
```

[Output1](https://eval.in/1026362)

[Output2](https://eval.in/1026364)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i prefer to get the keys than the value. your answer return only value from the first array. if the example : 
$arr1 = [0 => 100000,1 => 50000,2 => 100000,3 => 100000,4 => 100000, 5 => 100000];

$arr2 = [0 => 150000,1 => 200000, 2 => 200000];
then the result will be :
Array ( [150000] => Array ( [0] => 100000 [1] => 50000 ) [200000] => Array ( [0] => 100000 [1] => 100000 ) )

Answer (score -1):

Try with following code:

```
$arr = array(
0 => 100000,
1 => 50000,
2 => 100000,
3 => 100000);
$count = $val = 0;
$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $a){
   $val += $a;
   $count++;
   if($count == 2){
     $newArr[] = $val;
     $val = $count = 0; 
   }
}
print_r($newArr); die;
```

Comment: @Philipp He has mentioned, The problem is I want to get the combination from first array that formed second array.

Comment: Yeah -> input: first, second; output: combination used to build second.. read the comments

Comment: @Harkamal Philipp was right, sorry for my bad english